# how to use same functions in two javascript files

Tags: javascript, function

I have made a simple store in javascript. I have 1 html file with produkts and a checkoutcart that shows the items. I need to have 2 html files, one for products and one for the checkoutcart. Also two js files one for the product html, and one for the cart html. I have written my code so it works for 1 js and 1 html file. My functions are depended on eachother and I need some functions in both js files. Im using firebase for the products.

I have tried import/export. Also with setting data in localStorage from one js file and getting it in the other js file. How can I use same functions in other js files?

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="lang1" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta id="mode" name="color-scheme" content="light">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/scss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    
    <title>Hamburger</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="square">
    
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width:751px)" srcset="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/5499/5499206.png">
        
            <img>
        </picture>
    
        <div class="lang"><a href="/cart/cart.html"><i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></a><div class="lang1"></div></div>
        <div class="height"><i id="bar" class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i> </div>
        <div> 
            <ul class="menu hidden" id="menu" >
                <li id="home">Home</li>
                <li id="about">About</li>
                <li id="contact">Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="grid"  id="container">
            
            
        </div>
      
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div>copyright<i class="fa-regular fa-copyright"></i>Sneakerstore</div>
        <br>
        <div>info@sneakerstore.com</div>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-messenger"></i>
        <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="shoppingcontainer">
            
    </div>
    <button class="clearCart">Clear cart</button>
    <div>
        <div class="subtotal">Total price(0 items):</div>
        <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>
    </div>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script

```
const buyBtn = document.querySelector('button')
let cartNr = document.getElementById('cartNr')
const lang1 = document.querySelector('.lang1')
cartNr = 1
//add to cart array
let cart = []

//hämta från firebase render in DOM
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.grid')
let lager = 10
async function getProducts(){
  try{
    const baseURL = 'https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
    const url = baseURL + 'Products.json'
    const response = await fetch(url)
    let data = await response.json()
    console.log(data)

    
    const generatedHTML = Object.keys(data).reduce((accum, i) => 
      wrapper.innerHTML= accum +
    `<div  class="div-container">
      
      <div class="image"><img class="skor-img" src="${data[i].img}" alt=""></div>
      <div class="beskrivning"><strong class="text">${data[i].namn}</strong><br><br><p class="text2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum quas quasi praesentium voluptates minima deleniti enim sint quidem expedita sed ut officiis hic dolore dolor quaerat atque earum tenetur necessitatibus, maiores odit illo molestias voluptatibus adipisci quos? Vero necessitatibus tempora inventore, accusamus illo, maiores quisquam quo odit nesciunt qui nisi hic est non aliquid ex numquam earum aperiam? Recusandae excepturi eligendi nemo magni praesentium assumenda, placeat rem numquam illo provident earum officia eveniet tempora commodi laborum molestias animi expedita nihil sint explicabo quos modi at. Odio vel a voluptas explicabo pariatur.</p></div>
      <div class="pris"><p>lager: ${lager}</p> <button class="euro" onclick="addToCart(${data[i].id})">Buy:${data[i].pris}kr</button></div></div>`
    ,'' )
    
     
      
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML =generatedHTML 
  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
  

  }

getProducts()


  
//add products to cart function from firebase
 function addToCart(id){
  async function getAndAddToCart(){
  const baseURL = 'https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/'
  const url = baseURL + 'Products.json'
  const response = await fetch(url)
  let data = await response.json()

  lang1.innerHTML = `<div id="cartNr">${cartNr++}</div>`

    if(cart.some((item) => item.id === id)){
      changeNumberOfUnit("plus", id)
    }else{
    const arrayOfProductObjects = Object.values(data);
    const theProductToAdd = arrayOfProductObjects.find(product => product.id === id);
    console.log(theProductToAdd)
    cart.push({
      ...theProductToAdd,
      numberOfUnits: 1
    })
    console.log(cart)
    }
  }
  
  getAndAddToCart()
  //updateCart()
  
} 

//save in sessionstorage
// function saveinLocalStorage(){
//   localStorage.setItem('addedItems', JSON.stringify(cart))
//   console.log(cart)
// }

// const  getLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('addedItems'))
//   console.log(getLocalStorage) 

// cart.push(getLocalStorage)


///update Cart
function updateCart(){
renderCartItems()
renderSubtotal()
}

/// set TotalPrice
const subtotal = document.querySelector('.subtotal')
function renderSubtotal(){
let totalPrice = 0
cart.forEach((item) =>{
  totalPrice += item.pris * item.numberOfUnits
  
})
subtotal.innerHTML = `Total price ${totalPrice}kr:`
}

///render shoppingCart in DOM 
const shoppingcontainer = document.querySelector('.shoppingcontainer')
function renderCartItems(){
console.log(cart)
shoppingcontainer.innerHTML = ''
cart.forEach((item ) =>{
shoppingcontainer.innerHTML += `
<div class="cart-item">
    
      <div class="item-info">
        <h4>${item.namn}</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="unit-price">
        <small>${item.pris}kr</small>
      </div>
      <div class="units">
        <div class="btnminus" onclick"changeNumberOfUnit('minus', ${item.id})">-</div>
        <div class="number">${item.numberOfUnits}</div>
        <div class="btnplus" onclick"changeNumberOfUnit('plus', ${item.id})">+</div>
      </div>
  </div>
    `
})

}

///ClearCart remove items from cart
const clearCart = document.querySelector('.clearCart')
clearCart.addEventListener('click', (e) =>{
e.preventDefault()
removeItemsFromCart()
})



function removeItemsFromCart(){
//saveinSessionStorage()
  cart = []
  updateCart()
}

function changeNumberOfUnit(action, id){
    cart = cart.map((item) =>{

      let oldnumberOfUnits = item.numberOfUnits
      if(item.id === id){
          if(action === 'minus' && oldnumberOfUnits){
            oldnumberOfUnits--
          }else if(action === 'plus' && oldnumberOfUnits < item.lager){
            oldnumberOfUnits++
          }
      }
        return{
          ...item,
          numberOfUnits: oldnumberOfUnits
        }
    })
    updateCart()
}

//checkout buy
//Om användaren väljer att genomföra köpet ska saldot på firebase uppdateras och kundvagnen tömmas
const checkoutbtn = document.querySelector('.checkout')
checkoutbtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  checkout()

})

//checkout
function checkout( id){
  async function patchPost(obj){
    const baseURL = `https://webstore-22fa4-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/`
    const url = baseURL + 'Products.json'
        const init = {
            method: 'PATCH',
            body: JSON.stringify(obj),
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
            }
        };
    
        const response = await fetch(url, init)
        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
    }
    
    cart = cart.map((item) =>{

      let newLager = item.lager - item.numberOfUnits
      if(item.id === id){
      }
        return{
          lager: newLager
        }
    })  
    let obj = cart.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
      acc[i] = cur;
      return acc[i];
    }, {});

      patchPost(obj)
      console.log(obj)
      removeItemsFromCart()

    
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, but my best guess is that you're asking how to share functions across pages. In short, you need to move those functions to a third script and load it on both. Please see [ask], then revise to be more clear and specific.

Comment: yes i want to use same functions in 2 js files :) i have edited the question, thx

Comment: use node.js and look up module files

Comment: Your question is still very broad. It sounds like you're asking us to refactor your script to abstract the functions that should be shared. You'll have to give that a go yourself and come back with something more specific if you have problems.

Comment: I have rewrote the question again. I wonder how I can use same functions in two js files? or how I can import one function to another js file.